# Add another item in array mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm inserting a data into an array but when I insert the data, it overwrites the whole array, here is my router for updating array

```
router.put('/editbloodbankarray', function(req, res) {
        var editUser = req.body._id; 
        var newName = req.body.bloodbank_array; 
        User.findOne({ _id: editUser }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) throw err; 

                user.bloodbank_array = newName; 

                // Save changes
                user.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.json({ success: false, message: 'error' }); 
                    } else {
                        res.json({ success: true, message: 'Name has been updated!' }); 
                    }
                });

        });             
    });
```

**sample document:**

```
_id:5c8521c377df3158d0555db1,
bloodbank_array:
[
0:"1"
1:"2"
]
```

When I update/insert new item for example: 3..the array turns to:

```
_id:5c8521c377df3158d0555db1,
bloodbank_array:
[
0:"3"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the $push operator to do it directly (look [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) for more information) but since you already lookup the document first, you could just do `user.bloodbank_array.concat(newName);` instead of assigning a new value to the array like you do now with `user.bloodbank_array = newName`. The concat-function is a standard JS-function which inserts a new item at the end of an array. Fore more information you may read the [mozilla article](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the existing array.
Below is the line

```
user.bloodbank_array = newName;
```

Instead do a for loop on the `newName array` and push the items in `user.bloodbank_array`
like

```
for(int i=0;i<newName.length;i++)
{
    user.bloodbank_array.push(newName[i]);
}
```